# obtain en-US title tag text

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to obtain the text in only the title@lang=en-US elements in an XML file. 
This code obtains all the title text for all languages.

```
entries = root.xpath('//prefix:new-item', namespaces={'prefix': 'http://mynamespace'})
for entry in entries: 
    all_titles = entry.xpath('./prefix:title', namespaces={'prefix': 'http://mynamespace'})
    for title in all_titles:
       print (title.text)
```

I tried this code to get the title@lang=en-US text, but it does not work.

```
all_titles = entry.xpath('./prefix:title', namespaces={'prefix': 'http://mynamespace'})
for title in all_titles:
  test = title.xpath("@lang='en-US'")
  print (test)
```

How do I obtain the text for only the english language items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
//prefix:title[lang('en')]
```

will select all the English-language titles. Specifically:

- `title` elements that have an `xml:lang` attribute identifying the title as English, for example `<title xml:lang="en-US">` or `<title xml:lang="en-GB"`>
- `title` elements within some container that identifies all the contents as English, for example `<section xml:lang="en-US"><title/></section>`.

If you specifically want only US English titles, excluding other forms of English, then you can use the predicate `[lang('en-US')]`.

Comment: This answer worked when I did this: .//prefix:title[lang('en')]